# 'cout' does not name a type

Tags: c++, string, class, menu

Soy una principiante y necesito ayuda con esto.

```
"'cin' does not name a type".

"'cout' does not name a type".


#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class menu{
    public:
        int difficulty;
        string easy  = "ez";
        string middle = "middle";
        string hard = "hard";
        string broWhat = "BRO WHAT";
        
        string response = "idk bro u tell me";
        
        cout << "ez" << endl;
        cout << "middle" << endl;
        cout << "hard" << endl;
        cout << "BRO WHAT"<< endl;
        cout << "Choose a difficulty:" << endl;
        cin << response;
};


int main (){
    
    cout << menu.difficulty;
    
    return 0;
}
```

como sea, esto solo es un poco de practica en la que necesito ayuda

me pide que explique mas cosas pero creo que así esta bien, se
entiende? espero que si.
si hay alguna recomendacion por favor avisen.

Comment: Por favor, busca algún curso básico de C++ (hay muchos en Internet) y dale un repaso. Fuera del cuerpo de una función, solo puede haber declaraciones. Tus `cout << ...` deben de ir **dentro** del cuerpo de una función. Y para `cin`, has de usar el operador de extracción, `>>`. Un saludo.

Comment: Además de lo dicho, una vez creada la clase, has de instanciar un objeto de la misma. Es decir, crear un objeto del tipo "menu", y luego llamar a sus métodos. Algo como "menu M;" y "M.difficulty;"

Answer (score 0):

los errores aparecen debido a que tus 'cout' no se encuentran dentro de una funcion o un construcor;te aconsejo que lo que quieres que se ejecute primero en tu programa lo incluyas en un constructor que sera llamado al momento de la creacion del objeto de la clase.

Tamabien note esta linea:

```
cout << menu.difficulty;
```

Aui el error es que no has creado ningun objeto de tu clase 'menu' y eso te arrojara un error.Para solucionarlo podrias hacer esto:

```
menu aquielnombredetuobjeto;
aquielnombredetuobjeto.difficulty;
```

Eso te dara como resultado un cero ya que no le has asignado ningun valor a 'difficulty'.

Supongo que 'difficulty' es una funcion de tipo public perteneciente a tu clase menu.

Con todo lo antes mencionado asi quedaria tu codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class menu{
    private:
        string easy  = "ez";
        string middle = "middle";
        string hard = "hard";
        string broWhat = "BRO WHAT";
        string response = "idk bro u tell me";
    public:
        int difficulty(){
        cout << "ez" << endl;
        cout << "middle" << endl;
        cout << "hard" << endl;
        cout << "BRO WHAT"<< endl;
        cout << "Choose a difficulty:" << endl;
        cin >> response;
}
};


int main (){
    menu obj;//obj avrebiacion de objeto
    obj.difficulty();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Por cierto, tus strings los puse como variables privadas par que no puedan ser modificadas afuera de la clase y los operadores << solo se usan en cout y en los cin se usan >>(osea al revez).